# older javascript compatibility with Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

I am making a current product compatible with Internet Explorer 8. This product uses Javascript and I am trying to figure out why it does not work with IE8. I believe it is to do with the following code:

```
<div id="atag">

 $("#atag").dialog({
          .ghrd: gr,
          .hfdhf: hrg,
          .hfd: gdf
   });
```

Can anyone tell me how to update this to work with IE8?

Comment: What is the error? I can see syntax error in that code, the "keys" in the object literal should not start with "dot" (.)

Answer (score 2):

A couple of potential problems here. Firstly, you shouldn't have a dot in front of your property names (so instead of `.ghrd: gr` use `ghrd: gr`). Also, if it's working in IE9 but not IE8 then you may have a property name that IE8 is picking up as a reserved word, in which case you need to quote it (e.g. `"class": gr` rather than `class: gr`).

Comment: You *can* use dots at the front of the property name if you enclose them in quotes. It's not a good idea, but it can be done.

Comment: Ok, I need to explain it a bit moore. It works in the latest versions of Chrome, Safari, and Opera. It does not work in IE 6/7/8 or Firefox. It was built using ASP.NET MVC with jQuery, JSON and Cometd components. Hopefully this might shed some more light on it. Thank you for your help, I will try those suggestions and let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

I second MarkXA's answer, but there could potentially be more problems:

- Are gr, hrg and gdf variables defined in the scope you're trying to use them?
- Are you sure the .dialog component itself is compatible with IE8?
- Is it only broken in IE8, or also other browsers such as Firefox or Chrome?

Finally, we will be able to better help you if you post the JS error you get from IE.